# Inputting JsonObject to view Play framework / Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to take JsonObject as input to my project which i am using play framework with scala

@(name: String,tracks :Iterator[String],Track_Json:JsObject)

I guess i have to input it this way but JsObject cannot be found from the view level.

This is my definition of Json

```
val JsonObject= Json.obj(
  "var Json=" -> Json.arr(
    Json.obj(
      "id" -> "bob",
      "name" -> 31,
      "data" -> JsNull,
      "children" ->JsNull
    ),
    Json.obj(
      "id" -> "kiki",
      "name" -> 25,
      "data" -> JsNull,
      "children" ->JsNull
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fully qualified type name `play.api.libs.json.JsObject`